# Matching nonempty lines with pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to make a small application which uses `pyparsing` to extract data from files produced by another program.

These files have following format.

```
SOME_KEYWORD:
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4

ANOTHER_KEYWORD:
line a
line b
line c
```

How can i construct grammar which will help to extract `line 1`, `line 2` ... `line 4` and `line a` .. `line c`?
I am trying to make a construction like this

```
Grammar = Keyword("SOME_KEYWORD:").supress() + NonEmptyLines + EmptyLine.supress() +\
         Keyword("ANOTHER_KEYWORD:").supress() + NonEmptyLines + EmptyLine.supress()
```

But i don't know how to define `NonEmptyLines` and `EmptyLine`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My take on it:

```
    from pyparsing import *

    # matches and removes end of line
    EOL = LineEnd().suppress()

    # line starts, anything follows until EOL, fails on blank lines,
    line = LineStart() + SkipTo(LineEnd(), failOn=LineStart()+LineEnd()) + EOL

    lines = OneOrMore(line)

    # Group keyword probably helps grouping these items together, you can remove it
    parser = Keyword("SOME_KEYWORD:") + EOL + Group(lines) + Keyword("ANOTHER_KEYWORD:") + EOL + Group(lines)
    result = parser.parseFile('data.txt')
    print result
```

Result is:

```
['SOME_KEYWORD:', ['line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3', 'line 4'], 'ANOTHER_KEYWORD:', ['line a', 'line b', 'line c']]
```

Comment: +1, nice answer. This application is pretty line-oriented, so defining a LineEnd() expression is more or less unavoidable. Usually when you do this, you also want to redefine the default set of whitespace characters to not include `\n`, using:  `ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(" \t")`, right after importing pyparsing.  Then you'd be able to detect `LineEnd()*(2,None)` as the separater between keyword groups.

Answer (score 3):

This takes you most of the way there:

```
import pyparsing as pp

data = """
SOME_KEYWORD:
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4

ANOTHER_KEYWORD:
line a
line b
line c
"""

some_kw = pp.Keyword('SOME_KEYWORD:').suppress()
another_kw = pp.Keyword('ANOTHER_KEYWORD:').suppress()
kw = pp.Optional(some_kw ^ another_kw)

# Hint from: http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/message/view/home/21931601
lines = kw + pp.SkipTo(
    pp.LineEnd() + pp.OneOrMore(pp.LineEnd()) |
    pp.LineEnd() + pp.StringEnd() |
    pp.StringEnd()
)

result = lines.searchString(data.strip())
results_list = result.asList()
# => [['\nline 1\nline 2\nline 3\nline 4'], ['\nline a\nline b\nline c']]
```

When building a grammar it really helps to assign parts to variables and reference those when you can.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing