# Parse line data until keyword with pyparsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse line data and then group them in list.

Here is my script:

```
from pyparsing import *

data = """START
line 2
line 3
line 4
END
START
line a
line b
line c
END
"""

EOL = LineEnd().suppress()
start = Keyword('START').suppress() + EOL
end = Keyword('END').suppress() + EOL

line = SkipTo(LineEnd()) + EOL
lines = start + OneOrMore(start | end | Group(line))

start.setDebug()
end.setDebug()
line.setDebug()

result = lines.parseString(data)
results_list = result.asList()

print(results_list)
```

This code was inspired by another stackoverflow question:
[Matching nonempty lines with pyparsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822709/matching-nonempty-lines-with-pyparsing)

What I need is to parse everything from START to END line by line and save it to a list per group (everything from START to matching END is one group). However this script put every line in new group.

This is the result:

```
[['line 2'], ['line 3'], ['line 4'], ['line a'], ['line b'], ['line c'], ['']]
```

And I want it to be:

```
[['line 2', 'line 3', 'line 4'], ['line a', 'line b', 'line c']]
```

Also it parse an empty string at the end.

I'm a pyparsing beginner so I ask you for your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `nestedExpr` to find the text delimited by `START` and `END`.

If you use

```
In [322]: pp.nestedExpr('START', 'END').searchString(data).asList()
Out[322]: 
[[['line', '2', 'line', '3', 'line', '4']],
 [['line', 'a', 'line', 'b', 'line', 'c']]]
```

then the text is split on whitespace. (Notice we have `'line', '2'` above where we want `'line 2'` instead). We'd rather it just split only on `'\n'`. So to fix this we can use the `pp.nestedExpr` function's `content` parameter which allows us to control what is considered an item inside the nested list. 
The source code for `nestedExpr` defines

```
content = (Combine(OneOrMore(~ignoreExpr + 
                ~Literal(opener) + ~Literal(closer) +
                CharsNotIn(ParserElement.DEFAULT_WHITE_CHARS,exact=1))
            ).setParseAction(lambda t:t[0].strip()))
```

by default, where `pp.ParserElement.DEFAULT_WHITE_CHARS` is

```
In [324]: pp.ParserElement.DEFAULT_WHITE_CHARS
Out[324]: ' \n\t\r'
```

This is what causes `nextExpr` to split on all whitespace.
So if we reduce that to simply `'\n'`, then `nestedExpr` splits the content by
lines instead of by all whitespace.

---

```
import pyparsing as pp

data = """START
line 2
line 3
line 4
END
START
line a
line b
line c
END
"""

opener = 'START'
closer = 'END'
content = pp.Combine(pp.OneOrMore(~pp.Literal(opener) 
                                  + ~pp.Literal(closer) 
                                  + pp.CharsNotIn('\n',exact=1)))
expr = pp.nestedExpr(opener, closer, content=content)

result = [item[0] for item in expr.searchString(data).asList()]
print(result)
```

yields

```
[['line 2', 'line 3', 'line 4'], ['line a', 'line b', 'line c']]
```