# Group multiple sections (matches) using Pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I cannot figure out how to group zero or more repeating sections in text with [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/). In other words, I want to merge multiple matches into one named result set. Note, I want to use pyparsing as I have a lot of sections with different rules.

```py
from pyparsing import *    

input_text = """
Projects
project a created in c#

Education
university of college

Projects
project b created in python
"""

project_marker = LineStart() + Literal('Projects') + LineEnd()
education_marker = LineStart() + Literal('Education') + LineEnd()
markers = project_marker ^ education_marker

project_section = Group(
    project_marker + SkipTo(markers | stringEnd).setResultsName('project')
).setResultsName('projects')
education_section = Group(
    education_marker + SkipTo(markers | stringEnd).setResultsName('education')
).setResultsName('educations')
sections = project_section ^ education_section

text = StringStart() + SkipTo(sections | StringEnd())
doc = Optional(text) + ZeroOrMore(sections)
result = doc.parseString(input_text)

print(result)
# ['', ['Projects', '\n', 'project a created in c#'], ['Education', '\n', 'virginia tech'], ['Projects', '\n', 'project b created in python']]
print(result.projects)
# ['Projects', '\n', 'project b created in python']
print(result.projects[0].project)
# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'project'
```

Comment: Can a 'Projects' section contain more than one line describing a project? And similarly for 'Education' sections?

Comment: In your calls to `setResultsName` on project_section and education_section, add `listAllMatches=True`. Then I think your code will run as-is.

Comment: @PaulMcG Adding `listAllMatches=True` groups the results together, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @PaulMcG the solution is to add `listAllMatches=True` to `setResultsName`, see https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.ParserElement-class.html#setResultsName.

```
project_marker = LineStart() + Literal('Projects') + LineEnd()
education_marker = LineStart() + Literal('Education') + LineEnd()
markers = project_marker ^ education_marker

project_section = Group(
    project_marker + SkipTo(markers | stringEnd).setResultsName('project')
).setResultsName('projects', listAllMatches=True)
education_section = Group(
    education_marker + SkipTo(markers | stringEnd).setResultsName('education')
).setResultsName('educations', listAllMatches=True)
sections = project_section ^ education_section

text = StringStart() + SkipTo(sections | StringEnd())
doc = Optional(text) + ZeroOrMore(sections)
result = doc.parseString(input_text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my tentative answer, not that I'm proud of it. I cribbed a chunk of it from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5824309/131187.

```
>>> import pyparsing as pp
>>> pp.ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(" \t")
>>> EOL = pp.LineEnd().suppress()
>>> keyword = pp.Or([pp.Keyword('Projects'), pp.Keyword('Education')])
>>> line = pp.LineStart() + pp.NotAny(keyword) + pp.SkipTo(pp.LineEnd(), failOn=pp.LineStart()+pp.LineEnd()) + EOL
>>> lines = pp.OneOrMore(line)
>>> section = pp.Or([pp.Keyword('Projects'), pp.Keyword('Education')])('section') + EOL + lines('lines')
>>> sections = pp.OneOrMore(section)
>>> r = sections.parseString(input_text)
```

As you can see just below this sentence, the parser succeeds in gathering the information correctly, and in gathering it in such a way that it can be assembled, as will be shown presently. However, I cannot find a way of accessing all of the results from `parseString` that are so clearly available.

I resorted to applying `eval` to its `repr` representation. Having done that I was able to pick out all of the pieces and assign them to a dict-like object.

To be honest, this would be easier to do without pyparsing. Read a line, note whether it's a keyword. If it is, remember it. Then until you read another keyword just place all lines you read in a dictionary under the most recent keyword.

```
>>> repr(r)
"(['Projects', 'project 1', 'project 2', 'project 3', '', 'Education', 'institution 1', 'institution 2', 'institution 3', 'institution 4', '', 'Projects', 'assignment 5', 'assignment 8', 'assignment 10', ''], {'lines': [(['project 1', 'project 2', 'project 3', ''], {}), (['institution 1', 'institution 2', 'institution 3', 'institution 4', ''], {}), (['assignment 5', 'assignment 8', 'assignment 10', ''], {})], 'section': ['Projects', 'Education', 'Projects']})"
>>> evil_r = eval(repr(r))
>>> evil_r
(['Projects', 'project 1', 'project 2', 'project 3', '', 'Education', 'institution 1', 'institution 2', 'institution 3', 'institution 4', '', 'Projects', 'assignment 5', 'assignment 8', 'assignment 10', ''], {'lines': [(['project 1', 'project 2', 'project 3', ''], {}), (['institution 1', 'institution 2', 'institution 3', 'institution 4', ''], {}), (['assignment 5', 'assignment 8', 'assignment 10', ''], {})], 'section': ['Projects', 'Education', 'Projects']})
>>> evil_r[1]['lines']
[(['project 1', 'project 2', 'project 3', ''], {}), (['institution 1', 'institution 2', 'institution 3', 'institution 4', ''], {}), (['assignment 5', 'assignment 8', 'assignment 10', ''], {})]
>>> evil_r[1]['section']
['Projects', 'Education', 'Projects']
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> section_info = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, kind in enumerate(evil_r[1]['section']):
...     section_info[kind].extend(evil_r[1]['lines'][k][0][:-1])
>>> for section in section_info:
...     section, section_info[section]
...     
('Education', ['institution 1', 'institution 2', 'institution 3', 'institution 4'])
('Projects', ['project 1', 'project 2', 'project 3', 'assignment 5', 'assignment 8', 'assignment 10'])
```

**EDIT**: Or you could do this. Needs tidying up. At least it doesn't use anything unorthodox.

```
>>> input_text = open('temp.txt').read()
>>> import pyparsing as pp
>>> pp.ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(" \t")
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> class Accum:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.current_section = None
...         self.result = defaultdict(list)
...     def __call__(self, s):
...         if s[0] in ['Projects', 'Education']:
...             self.current_section = s[0]
...         else:
...             self.result[self.current_section].extend(s[:-1])
... 
>>> accum = Accum()
>>> EOL = pp.LineEnd().suppress()
>>> keyword = pp.Or([pp.Keyword('Projects'), pp.Keyword('Education')])
>>> line = pp.LineStart() + pp.NotAny(keyword) + pp.SkipTo(pp.LineEnd(), failOn=pp.LineStart()+pp.LineEnd()) + EOL
>>> lines = pp.OneOrMore(line)
>>> section = pp.Or([pp.Keyword('Projects'), pp.Keyword('Education')]).setParseAction(accum) + EOL + lines.setParseAction(accum)
>>> sections = pp.OneOrMore(section)
>>> r = sections.parseString(input_text)
>>> accum.result['Education']
['institution 1', 'institution 2', 'institution 3', 'institution 4']
>>> accum.result['Projects']
['project 1', 'project 2', 'project 3', 'assignment 5', 'assignment 8', 'assignment 10']
```

Comment: Another approach added.

Comment: Please use the '|' or '^' operators to combine alternate expressions, which cleans up the grammar a bit: `keyword = pp.Keyword('Projects') | pp.Keyword('Education')`. Pyparsing includes `restOfLine` as an easy way to read everything up to the next newline, so line simplifies to: `line = pp.LineStart() + pp.NotAny(keyword) + pp.restOfLine + EOL`. The last thing you need is to group each keyword and its associated lines, using the Group class: `section = pp.Group(keyword('section') + EOL + lines('lines'))`.

Comment: Lastly, print the results using `print(r.dump())`. This shows how you can access each parsed section such as `for section_data in r: print section_data.section`. No need for repr or eval. Read more about pyparsing's `ParseResults` class at https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.ParseResults-class.html.

Comment: @PaulMcG: Thank you! I hadn't been able to make `.Group` work in the way I wanted, and couldn't find `.restofline` in the doc. (Should have posted query on SO about the latter.)

Comment: @PaulMcG: For `r.asList` I get `[['Projects', 'project 1', 'project 2', 'project 3', ''], ['Education', 'institution 1', 'institution 2', 'institution 3', 'institution 4', ''], ['Projects', 'assignment 5', 'assignment 8', 'assignment 10', '']]`, which is not what I was aiming for. I had hoped to find a way of making pyparsing put all of the project items in one list and all of the education items in a separate list, as in my second script. Is there some way that isn't too arcane for a beginner?

Comment: @PaulMcG: I was hoping you would put your head in on this question. :)

Comment: Look at my comment on the original question - the OP is using results names on the overall 'Education' and 'Projects' sections, but the default in pyparsing will be to just keep the last one (similar to assigning keys in a dict). By adding 'listAllMatches=True' arg to setResultsName, then the projects and educations will be gathered together for your. Since you are using the `(name)` short-cut for setResultsName, try just adding a '*' at the end of the results name.

Comment: @PaulMcG: Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the help and introducing me to `restOfLine`.